# next/image does not load images from external URL

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to get images from cdn, but next reports error hostname **** is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`.According to the next official website, I added the following configuration in next.config.js, but it doesn’t work.

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'assets.example.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Next version is  12.3.1. What should I do to get the image correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved, because I set the domains of images to [] in the code behind

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `remotePatterns` if you just plan to use every path of a domain.

Instead, you can use `domains`:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ["assets.example.com"]
    }
}
```

Also, the fact that your snippet is not working seems to me as you had modified your `next.config.js` file but haven't restarted the server, if not, after every change to the config file you must stop the server and restart it with `npm run dev` to see the changes